# Django not checking paths in DIRS for files

Tags: python, django, django-templates, frameworks

I have a folder outside my templates file which I want to render I tried this:

```
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'projects')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

It doesn't work I want to render it like this:
`return render(request, f"{username}/{name}/index.html")`

Please help! Happy Coding!

Comment: That means you have a different template for each user? Likely you want to change the `urls`, and render it with the *same* template.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have some misunderstanding about how templates work. A template is a file that Django can use to *render* content to HTTP response. But this has *nothing* to do with the URL that will eventually render that view.

A view can render zero, one, or more templates, and should, eventually, simply return a HTTP response, whether there is a template that helps with that task does not matter.

You thus can define a url pattern that looks like:

```
urlpatterns = [
    # …,
    path('<str:username>/<str:name>/index.html', some_view, name='some-name'),
    # …,
]
```

and then use the view to render some template:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

def some_view(request, username, name):
    # …
    return HttpResponse(f'Hello {username}')
```

This simple view thus does not use any template, and simply response with a `'Hello username'`. If you render templates, then these do not have to use the same filename as the URL, you can use [**`render(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/http/shortcuts/#render) to render a template and thus make it easier to produce more sophisticated HTML, but a template is not required at all.

If you thus define a template, then usually you do that in the `app_name/templates/app_name/` directory, and a view usually uses the same template(s) for all calls to the same view (although that is not required either). For example if your app is named `users`, you can make a template in `users/templates/users/index.html`, and then render the view with:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def some_view(request, username, name):
    # …
    return render(request, 'users/index.html', {'username': username, 'name': name})
```